# Changing hue of SKSpriteNode textures on background thread

Tags: multithreading, swift, sprite-kit, core-graphics

I'm changing the hue of some of the sprites in a game I'm writing. The hue changing function is -

```
private func image(fromOriginalImage image: UIImage, withHue hue: CGFloat) -> UIImage
{
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), size: image.size)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, image.size.height)
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)

    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image.CGImage)

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Hue)

    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage) 
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.4, alpha: 1.0).CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

    let colouredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    return colouredImage
}
```

This works fine on a background thread, then I take the image it returns back onto the main thread to update the SKSpriteNode's textures, & occasionally I'll get a significant stutter in the game play -

```
GCD.async
{
    if let colouredImage = self.image(fromOriginalImage: image, withHue: hue)
    {
        GCD.async_main
        {
            self.texture = SKTexture(image: colouredImage)
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone's got any suggestions how to do this better, I'd be very happy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to put the texture change into an SKAction -

```
GCD.async
{
    if let colouredImage = self.image(fromOriginalImage: image, withHue: hue)
    {
        let changeTexture = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(image: colouredImage))
        self.runAction(changeTexture)
    }
}
```

The spriteKit engine handles it in its own time...